# QComboBox Qt Creator signals slots never fire

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a very simple Qt window that contains combo box, and I try to create signal slots for this combo box with Qt Creator. I tried `activated`, `currentIndexChanged`, `currentTextChanged`, nothing works.
What may be the reason?
Other signals (button click, menu item click) on the same window fire normally. Operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: on which action? user\automatic? not enough info.

Comment: Posting the code might help

Comment: I can not post entire project, it is too big and also private. However, signal assignment code is generated by Qt Creator itself, so I am not sure how may it be different between my Qt Creator and any other forumer Qt Creator. Window header file contains `private slots: void on_ComoboBox_activated(int index);`, and .cpp file contains this method body, nothing else.

Comment: You shall create an SSCCE, if you really need an answer.

Comment: This problem disappeared when I removed combo box from form and added it back with Qt Creator. So it looks like it is Qt Creator bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create slots in Qt Designer, on a Form, like a `QMainWindow` Form, if you right click and `Go to slot...`, it uses naming conventions to automagically connect the ui form elements to slots based on their name.

After you create those slots, you go and change the object name to something else.

Like instead of `comboBox1`, you change it to `myComboBox`, it will break the automagically connected ui form elements, because the name is different.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections

> ### Widgets and Dialogs with Auto-Connect
>
> Although it is easy to implement a custom slot in the dialog and
>   connect it in the constructor, we could instead use `QMetaObject`'s
>   auto-connection facilities to connect the OK button's `clicked()` signal
>   to a slot in our subclass. uic automatically generates code in the
>   dialog's `setupUi()` function to do this, so we only need to declare and
>   implement a slot with a name that follows a standard convention:
>
> ```
> void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
> ```

That is the most likely reason why your combobox started to not connect.

If it wasn't that you can see the output of every explicit connect call when they fail based on naming:

```
QObject::connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(misspelled_signal()), this, SLOT(non_existent_slot()));
```

And you will get very useful output in your `Application Output` tab at runtime to help diagnosis the errors.

Hope that helpls.